# Accessing unknown child

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, parent-child

In my code, I need to find a child of a child of a child.

Only the first child will always be the same child but the child of the child is randomized between 4 different possible prefabs.

on that last child I want to disable it's image.

here would be the ideal code if the child wouldn't be randomized between others:

```
protected void SetUnpickedPrizesVisibility(bool isVisible)
{
    foreach (var element in list)
    {
        if (!element.IsPicked)
        {             element.transform.FindChild("FirstChild").FindChild("SecondChild").FindChild("ThirdChild").GetComponent<Image>().enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

But since, the SecondChild varies, I can't simply do that.

Is my only option to do something like this?

```
protected void SetUnpickedPrizesVisibility(bool isVisible)
{
    foreach (var element in list)
    {
        if (!element.IsPicked)
        {
        if(element.transform.FindChild("FirstChild").FindChild("SecondChild1"))
            element.transform.FindChild("FirstChild").FindChild("SecondChild1").FindChild("ThirdChild").GetComponent<Image>().enabled = false;

        if(element.transform.FindChild("FirstChild").FindChild("SecondChild2"))
            element.transform.FindChild("FirstChild").FindChild("SecondChild2").FindChild("ThirdChild").GetComponent<Image>().enabled = false;

        if(element.transform.FindChild("FirstChild").FindChild("SecondChild3"))
            element.transform.FindChild("FirstChild").FindChild("SecondChild3").FindChild("ThirdChild").GetComponent<Image>().enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Or does someone have a different idea?

I know this is a very confusing to read question but I tried my best to simplify it.

Thanks,

Comment: **Let your children do it** : Create a script and attach it to every element in list so they can enable/disable on their own based of your `IsPicked` check. No need to go through all of them from a different script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So why not add a script to the prefab of the last child that disables the image. That way you only need to keep a reference to the script when you instantiate it and not go looking for the children.

Comment: Perfect, I can't believe I didn't think of that! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just search through, something like this:

```
    foreach (var element in list)
    {
        if (!element.IsPicked)
        {
            foreach(var grandChild in element)
            {
                foreach(var greatGrandChild in grandChild)
                {
                    greatGrandChild.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = false;
                }
            }          
        }
    }
```

It's easier to use `child`, `grandChild` and `greatGrandChild` rather than child of the child of child :-)